Identifying files with unique contents from across multiple directories
I want to extract the paths of all files with unique contents from a directory parent_dir recursively. All of them have the same file name, summary.txt. Their paths look like this:
parent_dir/sub_dir_1/sum_1/A/../B/summary.txt
However, sum_1 is linked, so I can also access summary.txt as
parent_dir/sub_dir_1/sum_1/summary.txt.
Now I want to extract the paths of all such "summary.txt" from parent_dir such that all of them have unique contents, and I'm writing a python code for it.
I tried this:
... 
List = glob.glob('parent_dir/**/summary.txt', recursive=True)
Newer_list = [List[0]]
for file_1 in List:
    for file_2 in Newer_list:
        if not filecmp.cmp(file_1, file_2, shallow=False):
            Newer_list.append(file_1)
...


This means glob.glob(...) returns paths of both the formats, hence I tried a workaround to 'cleanse' the List after glob.glob() extracts all path files. However this has a long run time, and considering I'll have to work with potentially large number of files I want to avoid this.
Almost all the files have very similar sizes, so I think comparing sizes isn't the most effective solution either.
I considered using set() method to remove the non-unique files from List but since a single file can have two different paths I'm not sure if it'll work.
fdupes seems to be a good choice but it returns duplicate files, the opposite of what I want to do. And I'm not really sure how to fit it in my code either.
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

pathlib has a resolve() method that will uniquely/absolutely identify files https://pymotw.com/3/pathlib/index.html

Sorry for the late reply. It serves my need to some extent, but it doesn’t seem to uniquely identify files if they have paths as parent_dir/sub_dir_1/sum_1/summary.txt, and parent_dir/sub_dir_2/sum_2/summary.txt, even if both of them have the same contents, @MarkSetchell. I want to be able to chuck out either of the paths because the other path contains a file with the same contents.

I don't understand what you are trying to do, but maybe you could hash the files with mdsum.

It just occurred to me that I need not worry about whatever I asked in my last comment, which means I require just resolve() for whatever purpose I had in mind. Thanks for the suggestions though!
